# Is using -S with JRuby recommended even when using a Ruby version manager?

Tags: jruby

Based on [this page on the JRuby wiki](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/GettingStarted) and other resources I see the recommendation is

> to always use `jruby -S`.

because

> The `-S` parameter tells JRuby to use its version of the installed binary, as opposed to some other version (such as an MRI version) that might be on your `PATH`.

Using rbenv and rvm I've had issues when using `-S` with JRuby (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531441/jruby-installation-failing-unless-sudo-with-undefined-local-variable-or-method)) and my understanding is that both those version managers solve the problem `-S` attempts to address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to run the *gem* command with `jruby -S gem` if you are using a Ruby manager such as *rbenv* or *rvm*. Those tools manage your command path for you so that the correct Ruby runtime and the correct version of rubygems are used. Similar applies to the *rake*.

Comment: So to clarify, even with a Ruby version manager `-S` is still recommended at runtime? I'm still confused as to why one case applies during bundling and another during runtime...

Comment: When you run a shell command such as `gem`, `rake` or `bundle`, you are at the mercy of your shell's command path. If you have that misconfigured, you may end up launching a different Ruby runtime than you expect. A Ruby version manager manages your command path for you, and so `gem` or whatever is always run with the Ruby runtime you expect.

Thus it is never necessary to run _gem_ as `jruby -S gem` if you use a Ruby version manager.